# Linux RHEL5.2 VM Won't boot - Cannot fsck to repair

Tags: linux, redhat, mount, boot, fsck

I have a redhat 5.2 VM which will not boot on VMWare...

[image]

I've tried logging into maintenance mode and adding a file 'forcefsck' to /, which forced a check on next boot... that didnt get me anywhere and I ended up in the same place.

It's telling me that /dev/sdb1 is mounted, however when I try umount /dev/sdb1 is says /dev/sdb1 not found...

[image]

Has anyone come across this before or can point me in the right direction?

EDIT 1 : Contents of FSTAB
[image]

EDIT 2 : Result of 'umount -a'...[image]

EDIT 3 : Result of 'fsck /dev/sdb'...[image]

EDIT 4 : Result of 'fsck.ext3 /dev/sdb'[image]

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/fstab? Is /dev/sdb1 the partition for /media? If so you could just comment that line out and that should let the server boot (at which point you can investigate more easily).

Comment: RHEL 5.2 [Extended Update Support](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata#Extended_Update_Support) has been ended March 31, 2010.

Comment: Added image to post with contents of fstab :)

Comment: @John I think your `sdb` disk died or is unaccessible. Please, show us output of command `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/`.

Comment: Also show motherboard model. Does motherboard BIOS show current date after full power off (with ejection of power cord)?

Comment: You can comment the `/dev/sdb1` line in `/etc/fstab` and then you'll boot the server.

Comment: What is the label of the file system on `/dev/sdb1`?

Answer (score 1):

After looking to your `fstab` I could offer you execute `umount -a`, to unmount all partitions and after this run `fsck` for /dev/sdb or all drives.

Comment: This seems to be having problems too :( See additional image at bottom of my post...

Comment: @John well, if your partitions not mounted, could you try to execute `fsck /dev/sdb`.

Comment: See new screengrab... 'the superblock could not be read...'. :(

Comment: @John try `fsck.ext3`

Comment: identical error...

Comment: Well, you could try to run `e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdb`, but I'll offer you to make snapshot for this vmdk to prevent dataloss. Because all commands before was safe,